# Open facebook profile from the my custom app based on userid (fb://profile/userid) its open but give message the page you requested was not found

Tags: swift

```
let proURL = "fb://profile/\(userId)" 
if let url = URL(string: proURL), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
      if #available(iOS 10, *) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: {
                            (success) in
        })
      } else {
          UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
      }
}
```

Here I take user profile Id and based on that I will open profile in app, but it gives me error :

> the page you requested was not found